# Keyboard shortcut for going onelevel up in midnight commander [mc]

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mc

[image]

Is there a keyboard shortcut for going one level up in the directory tree in midnight commander (mc), which will save me from going all the up to the `..`?

As shown below - say I'm in a directory that contains tonnes of stuff, and its painful to scroll all the way up. Its clickable, but nothing beats keyboard shortcuts!

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you go to **Options->Panel-Options** and tick the "**Lynx-like motion**" option you can use left-arrow to go to the parent directory and right-arrow to enter a directory.

Comment: I have changed my OS, and haven't been using mc. So sorry for the delay in accepting this as the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 12):

Does <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> count as a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: That, or `^.` (ctrl+period) followed by `Enter` works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: Ctrl + PageUp goes to the last diretory - not the parent, but this may be what you want in most cases.
(https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/2420)

Comment: Sheesh! Anyway to map a key combinations?

Comment: My gnome terminal overrides the controls of `Ctrl+PageUP` and switches to the other tab that is opened. `alt+home` on the other has the same effect of taking it to top of directory listing `..`. Need to hit enter and go up ... Thanks for the answer anyway ...

Answer (score 6):

Without changing the default setup <kbd>Alt + Y</kbd> and <kbd>Alt + U</kbd> go to previous and next directory in history, which may be enough on most cases ([<kbd>Alt + H</kbd> to see the full **h**istory](http://www.keyxl.com/aaae4b0/407/midnight-commander-keyboard-shortcuts.htm)). If not, [you always have <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21224495/4970442).

<kbd>Alt + Arrows</kbd> are used to move between windows on [byobu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038860/349837)/tmux.

To add a custom shortcut (like <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) to your user config:

```bash
echo 'CdParentSmart = backspace' >> ~/.config/mc/mc.keymap  # Globally in /etc/mc/mc.keymap
```

[Here](http://klimer.eu/2015/05/01/use-midnight-commander-like-a-pro/) more related handy shortcuts, and [here](https://cheatography.com/hank/cheat-sheets/midnight-commander/) a popular cheatsheet.

Comment: Note, that 'CdParentSmart = backspace' should be added to [panel] section

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/mc/mc.default.keymap` find and uncomment `CdParentSmart` in `[Panel]` section. If it's not there, add it. And set a key you want. Behavoir similar to Total/Double Commander would be `CdParentSmart = backspace`. So it will backspace command line, if it's not empty. Or will level up from any place, if command line is empty.
The file should be edited when MC is not running, as it is resetting it to currently loaded settings on exit.

Comment: Or simply create file ~/.config/mc/mc.keymap with following content:

[panel]
CdParentSmart = backspace

Answer (score 0):

```js
sudo sed -i 's/#CdParentSmart =.*/CdParentSmart = backspace/g' /etc/mc/mc.keymap
```